# Subsetting for proportional representation in R

Tags: r, function, math, subset

I can't wrap my tiny brain around this one. One dataframe contains observations, each with a gender and an age bracket. I'm trying to write a function that returns a subset of the rows of this dataframe where each age-gender combination appears in a proportion roughly equal to the value in the "props" dataframe. Ideally, the function will trim as few observations as possible. The results can be approximate (By approximate/roughly equal, I mean that each group's representation in the output should be at least within 5% of the desired proportion, and generally as low as possible).

```
ages <- c("18-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59","60+")
genders <- c("M","F")

set.seed(101)
df <- data.frame("id" = paste0("p",c(1:500)),
             "gender" = sample(genders, replace=TRUE, size=500),
             "age" = sample(ages, replace=T, size=500))

props <- data.frame("age" = c(ages, ages),
                "gender" = genders,
                "pcts" = c(.0835, .1145, .1145, .1145, .073, .0835, .1145, 
                           .1145, .1145, .073))

select_max <- function(df, props) {

....   

return(subset)
}
```

I experimented with solutions using least common multiples and greatest common divisors, but these fell apart when the proportions didn't work nicely together. I'm considering a solution which adds and subtracts rows one at a time until it gets close enough to the desired proportions, but I feel there must be some more elegant solution. All help is appreciated. This is a fun one, for sure.

Comment: Do you plan to make statistical inferences from these results? Do you have methods planned that take non-random sampling into account? Does every sample have to to have the same number from each group? What exactly does "roughly equal" and "the results can be approximate" mean exactly?

Comment: Hi @MrFlick. I do not plan to make statistical inferences from the results, it serves another purpose. I'll try to answer all of your other questions in an edit to the my question. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "Does every sample have to have the same number from each group?".

Comment: One approach is to separate the groups, and sample a fixed number (as determined by the desired proportion) from each group. You can make the proportions the same as in the original data, or something else, if it turns out that's useful to you.

Comment: @RobertDodier Yes I suppose the question is, how can I automate the calculation of those fixed numbers so that they use as much of the available data as possible?

Comment: On rereading the question, I think I understand better now. I think you want m[k] equal to the integer nearest (M times props[k]) where m[k] is the number of items to sample from group k and M is the total number of samples you want. You might need to adjust m[k] by plus or minus one to get the sum of all m[k] to add up to exactly M.